# Ender 5 plus - leveling

Tags: troubleshooting, bed-leveling, bltouch, creality-ender-5

My Ender 5 plus developed a strange issue. The printer is always moving the bed a couple of mm from the nozzle. I have releveled the bed a couple of times, that does not solve it. I did also a manual adjustment, e.g. started the print and then adjust the Z-axis until the nozzle is at the right height to get the layer at the bed. When I stop the print and then restart the print, it set the nozzle at the same previous distance.

It did store the Z-axis offset, but somehow it is being ignored. I have checked the firmware version which is 1.70.2. That firmware came with the printer and seems to be a later version than what is available on the Creality website. I did not make any modifications to the printer.

Comment: Also used a different slicer now to see if it was an issue with the slicer. Same issue.

Comment: Does it save your new z-offset in memory? You can check this in configuration menu. Also check, if you offset in your slicer.

Comment: What controller board do you have?